# How to configure the below nginx annotation in istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, servicemesh

How can add the below ssl-redirect configuration in istio ingress gateway?

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
 nginx.ingress.kubernertes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
```

Are there any annotations in istio gateway or any other configuration to be done on the envoy filter to make the ssl-redirect false?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option in istio is to specify "httpsRedirect" attribute to false in gateway definition which will stop the redirection.

Below is the sample definition.  More details are in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: some-config-namespace
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-gateway-controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - uk.bookinfo.com
    - eu.bookinfo.com
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true # sends 301 redirect for http requests
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-443
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - uk.bookinfo.com
    - eu.bookinfo.com
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE # enables HTTPS on this port
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/servercert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
  - port:
      number: 9443
      name: https-9443
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "bookinfo-namespace/*.bookinfo.com"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE # enables HTTPS on this port
      credentialName: bookinfo-secret # fetches certs from Kubernetes secret
```